# Accessing field data from table in a deep structure?

Tags: nested, structure, abap

I would like to access data from the (in image) highlighted field ID from item table, which exists in a deep nested structure.
I'd then perform various checks if whether the data is initial. In other cases, I'd actually pick data from one of these fields, and input in another field of another table in the deep structure.

What would be the best way to approach this task?

Here is a snippet from what I have to work with:

[image]

[image]

Comment: afaik navigating through the nested structure of your webservice is the only thing you can do. in terms of performance if would work with read table, sy-subrc and is initial ... please share if you find a "smarter" way of doing this.

Comment: Just declare DespatchedDeliveryNotification_in_V1 type and use field access as usual: `desp-input-delivery-Item-ID = 'something'`. What are the complications do you have?

Comment: @Suncatcher I get errors like it_delivery_PO_ref is unknown and ls_wa_1 is a table without header line. How can I fix my code: pastebin.com/ER0GTdRV

Comment: It seems that `PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ID` is not a table, but a flat type. What is `SHP_DSPTCHD_DELIV_NOTIF_V1_MT`? Where did you get it? Show the screenshot from SE11

Comment: @Suncatcher I have added a new screenshot on my original post. Basically I need to check whether PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ID and  PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ITEM_ID are empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a table type INPUT-DELIVERY-ITEM. Assign data from ITEM to your table. 
Loop the table to access inside rows.

Or just loop the entire INPUT-DELIVERY-ITEM directly.

Comment: I get errors like it_delivery_PO_ref is unknown and ls_wa_1 is a table without header line.

How can I fix my code: https://pastebin.com/ER0GTdRV

Comment: apparently from the 1st screen shot, the `ITEM-ID` is not a table type entity. It is a normal field type CHAR length 10. Also I don't see `PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE` in the 1st screenshot. Where did it come from?

Comment: I have added a new screenshot on my original post. Basically I need to check whether PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ID and  PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ITEM_ID are empty or not.

Comment: can you try this: `LOOP TABLE INPUT-DELIVERY-ITEM` into work area named `LINE_ITEM` (for example). Now I think you can access inner value with path `LINE_ITEM-PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ID` and `LINE_ITEM-PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ITEM_ID` inside `LOOP ENDLOOP` statement

Comment: I just checked your Pastebin snippet. You only declare `it_delivery_Item` and didn't assign data for it. `it_delivery_Item = SHP_DSPTCHD_DELIV_NOTIF_V1_MT-DESPATCHED_DELIVERY_NOTIF_V1-DELIVERY-ITEM. LOOP AT it_delivery_Item INTO DATA(ls_wa_1). IF ls_wa_1-PURCHASE_ORDER_REFERENCE-ID IS INITIAL` might work for you

Comment: thats simple structure navigation... maybe you should learn abap table type and structure type? the amount of questions is ridiculous on this.